# How do I create terrain texture maps from photogrammetry?

Tags: textures

I want to create a terrain texture diffuse and normal map.

To do that, I have capture some terrain with photogrammety:

[image]

I have cleaned up the high poly model and created a lo poly model from it in ZBrush.
Then I unwrapped it in ZBrush, and I got this non-rectangular UV map:

[image]

How could I bake a rectangular normal map from the high and low poly unwrapped model?

Typical terrain normal maps look like that me (just like the diffuse map):

[image]

How could I create such a rectangle normal map with my approach? I don't want to use CrazyBump or Bitmap2Material. I would like to use my hi / lo poly model to create the normal map.

Thank you!

Comment: Unwrapping to a non-rectangular map is counter-intuitive. I would instead (in code) select a square section from the original model / point-cloud, and use that as the basis for generating a normal map. How you do this depends on tools you have or are willing and/or able to code up. I might, for instance, sample the height gridwise at some pre-decided resolution across the selected rectangular space, from the original dataset, produce a heightmap, then use that high res heightmap to produce the normal map. You could also produce the normal map directly, if you have the req'd geometry and means.